# Get certain part of url and use a WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, url

How do I get a certain part of the url?

Example: bithumor.co/posts/12345

How do I get the "12345" part so it can be put in the WHERE clause of the mysql(i) query and SELECT the post from the database where id = 12345 (when on the webpage: bithumor.co/posts/12345)

Example:

```
SELECT post_ id FROM post WHERE id = ["12345" part of url]
```

I already have bithumor.co/posts?id=12345 sorta thing

Comment: Is the URL always in the format bithumor.co/co/somethingyouwantokeep?

Comment: I think you want to set this up in your htaccess file, you can rewrite urls so that `/posts/24234` is equivalent to `posts.php?id=24234`  check out htaccess rewrite

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: *a little short* or *little shorts Sam?* - Summer's here, remember that ;-) @JayBlanchard

Comment: http://php.net/parse_url

Comment: @RightClick how do I go about rewriting htaccess? What are the codes I need? I am not exactly familiar with it.

Comment: search the internet for `htaccess RewriteRule` and please remove swag from your username.  You must earn the swagger

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you could use a rewrite in your htaccess to form a get request to your PHP script then just access the `id` as you would any GET parameter.

```
RewriteRule    ^posts/([0-9]+)$    posts.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

Or if you want to do it from pure PHP that is a choice too.

```
$tokens = explode("/", $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
$number = $tokens[count($tokens) - 1];
$query = 'SELECT post_ id FROM post WHERE id = "' . $number . '"';
```